# Knowledge as part of Managed Package. Limitations?

Tags: managed-package, knowledge, lightning-knowledge

We are planning to have knowledge as part of our managed package. I found [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000355272&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1) article stating :

> It is not currently possible or supported to include Lightning Knowledge as managed package components.

We have new record types and page layouts and Custom buttons defined as part of Knowledge objects. Are there any limitations that SFDC does not allow knowledge modifications as part of managed package?